# Drawing marker top of a line

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to draw a line on top of another line using open layer. The idea is draw a second line top of the predefined line path. [image: sample image line overlay]

How can we draw a line with starting coordinate and distance on top of the predefined line path?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by returning a 2nd style from your layer's style function, which has a custom geometry derived from the original one:

```js
var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style(...); // your existing style
var secondLineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  ... // styles for the 2nd line
  geometry: function(feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry().clone();
    ... // modify the geometry, e.g. using forEachSegment and getCoordinateAtM
    return geometry;
  }
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return [
      lineStyle,
      secondLineStyle
    ];
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes. It will only work if you have multiple line segments. If it is only two line segments, and if you want to put it some where in one line segment based on the distance, How can we achieve that?